# trouble with hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

Im using the following code within a method called a_level:

```
if(@program.theme==MyHelper::TemplateConstants::DEFAULT_LAYOUT)
  style = 'border: none'
elsif(@program.theme == MyHelper::TemplateConstants::LOGO_LAYOUT)
  style = 'border: top'
end
```

And the following within a method called b_level:

```
if(@program.theme==MyHelper::TemplateConstants::DEFAULT_LAYOUT)
  style = 'color: #888;'
elsif(@program.theme == MyHelper::TemplateConstants::LOGO_LAYOUT)
  style = 'color: #666;'
```

in the same helper. I want to use a hash instead, something like

```
my_styles = { :level_a => {... }, :level_b => {...} }
```

Im not getting it right. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you say not getting it right what do you mean? Have you tried `style_hash = Hash[:program_logo => blah, :do_not_reply => foo]`?

Comment: Just updated my comment as you were leaving yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
style_hash = {
    :program_logo => {
        UserMailerHelper::EmailTemplateConstants::DEFAULT_WITH_BANNER => 'border: none;height:50px;float:left; margin-right: 10px; padding: 2px;',
        UserMailerHelper::EmailTemplateConstants::LOGO_AT_BOTTOM => 'border: none;height:80px; padding: 2px 0px 2px 2px;'
    },
    :do_not_reply => {
        UserMailerHelper::EmailTemplateConstants::DEFAULT_WITH_BANNER => 'color: #888; padding-top: 5px; display:block; text-align:center',
        UserMailerHelper::EmailTemplateConstants::LOGO_AT_BOTTOM => 'color: #888; padding-top: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #D7D4C6;'
    }
}
```

and then in `program_logo`:

```
style = style_hash[:program_logo][@program.email_theme]
```

and in `do_not_reply`:

```
style = style_hash[:do_not_reply][@program.email_theme]
```

Or perhaps it would make more sense to arrange your `style_hash` like this:

```
style_hash = {
    UserMailerHelper::EmailTemplateConstants::DEFAULT_WITH_BANNER => {
        :program_logo => 'border: none;height:50px;float:left; margin-right: 10px; padding: 2px;',
        :do_not_reply => 'color: #888; padding-top: 5px; display:block; text-align:center'
    },
    UserMailerHelper::EmailTemplateConstants::LOGO_AT_BOTTOM => {
        :program_logo => 'border: none;height:80px; padding: 2px 0px 2px 2px;',
        :do_not_reply => 'color: #888; padding-top: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #D7D4C6;'
    }
}
```

And then access it like this:

```
# program_logo
style = style_hash[@program.email_theme][:program_logo]
# do_not_reply
style = style_hash[@program.email_theme][:do_not_reply]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch ! I liked the second approach more, would make it easier for me to add more email templates later.

Comment: @Appster: I prefer the second one as well, it lets you pull out a whole theme as a single Hash; the first one feels a bit backwards.